# How to keep specific object properties from an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, each object has a parent and that parent has children.

**I want to have an array that contains only the name and id of the parent and the name and id of his children. The following example shows how one object currently looks.**

```
@id: "/course_categories/1"
@type: "CourseCategory"
children: Array(5)
   0: {@id: "/course_categories/2", @type: "CourseCategory", id: 2, name: "PHP voor beginners", left: 2, …}
   1: {@id: "/course_categories/3", @type: "CourseCategory", id: 3, name: "PHP advanced", left: 40, …}
   2: {@id: "/course_categories/4", @type: "CourseCategory", id: 4, name: "PHP voor dummies", left: 42, …}
   3: {@id: "/course_categories/5", @type: "CourseCategory", id: 5, name: "PHP voor experts", left: 44, …}
   4: {@id: "/course_categories/6", @type: "CourseCategory", id: 6, name: "PHP design patterns", left: 46, …}
id: 1
key: "0-1"
left: 1
level: 0
name: "PHP"
parent: null
right: 48
```

How I want it to be:

```
data: [{
  title: 'PHP', id: 1, children: [
    {
      title: 'PHP voor beginners', id: 2, children: []
    },
    {
      title: 'PHP advanced', id: 3, children: []
    },
    {
      // PHP voor dummies, PHP voor experts, etc...
    }
  ]
},
{
  title: 'REACT', id: 4, children: [
    {
      title: 'React voor beginners', id: 5, children: [
        {
          title: 'React voor beginners 2', id: 6, children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      // ....
    }
  ]
}]
```

It is also possible that a child has it owns children. So the children of a child should have the same format. (example above) I know this can be achieved by using a recursive function but I'm wondering what the best approach would be for filtering my current object.

Comment: Do you intend that `name` should be transformed to `title`?

Comment: Yes, exactly @OliverRadini

Comment: I've now updated the answer to also transform `name` to `title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to remove properties from an object by filtering the keys, then using `reduce` to get an object from the keys that remain. You can call this function recursively to do the same for the children.

You can then write a separate function to transform the `name` property into `title`:

```js
const data = [{
  "@id": "/course_categories/1",
  "@type": "CourseCategory",
  children: [{
      "@id": "/course_categories/2",
      "@type": "CourseCategory",
      id: 2,
      name: "PHP voor beginners",
      left: 2,
    },
    {
      "@id": "/course_categories/3",
      "@type": "CourseCategory",
      id: 3,
      name: "PHP advanced",
      left: 40,
    },
    {
      "@id": "/course_categories/4",
      "@type": "CourseCategory",
      id: 4,
      name: "PHP voor dummies",
      left: 42,
    },
    {
      "@id": "/course_categories/5",
      "@type": "CourseCategory",
      id: 5,
      name: "PHP voor experts",
      left: 44,
    },
    {
      "@id": "/course_categories/6",
      "@type": "CourseCategory",
      id: 6,
      name: "PHP design patterns",
      left: 46,
    }
  ],
  id: 1,
  key: "0-1",
  left: 1,
  level: 0,
  name: "PHP",
  parent: null,
  right: 48,
}]

const keepProperties = (object, properties) => {
  const objectWithOnlyRequiredProperties = Object.keys(object)
    .filter(key => properties.indexOf(key) > -1)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
      ...prev,
      [curr]: object[curr],
    }), {});

  const children = object.hasOwnProperty('children') ?
    object.children.map(child => keepProperties(child, properties)) : [];

  return {
    ...objectWithOnlyRequiredProperties,
    children,
  };
}

const transformNameToTitle = object => {
  const children = object.hasOwnProperty('children') ? {
    children: object.children.map(transformNameToTitle)
  } : false;

  const objectKeysWithoutName = Object
    .keys(object)
    .filter(key => key !== 'name')

  const objectWithoutName = keepProperties(
    object,
    objectKeysWithoutName,
  );

  return {
    ...objectWithoutName,
    title: object.name,
    ...children,
  }
}

const test = transformNameToTitle(
  keepProperties(data[0], ['name', 'id'])
);

console.dir(test)
```